# Am I waiving liability insurance coverage by agreeing to this boat charter contract clause?

Tags: contract-law, insurance

> Member shall be liable for any and all bodily injury, death, property
>   damage and or loss to the boat, its gear and equipment whatsoever and
>   howsoever caused by either the negligence of Member, Member's guests
>   or crew, or the alleged negligence of the company during the term of
>   Member's charter of a boat. Member accepts the in force insurance
>   deductibles of the boat as member's liability for the boat during the
>   term of Member's charter. Purchase of the damage waiver reduces
>   Charterer's liability for the chartered vessel to the current
>   insurance deductible to a maximum of $1600.00. This damage waiver does
>   not provide personal injury, death, or property liability protection
>   for Charterer. The liability insurance maintained on the vessel by the
>   company, affiliated companies, or chartered vessel's owner(s), is
>   excess over any applicable insurance carried by Charterer.

The clause calls out special cases for negligence and property liability but I cannot tell whether I would have liability coverage in the event of an accident where I am not deemed to be negligent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No

It specifically says that your liability for damage to the boat is limited to the insurance deductibles. Your liability for other loss is unlimited and uninsured - get your own life, health, public risk etc. insurance.